# What's the conda package for the `sort` command line utility?

Tags: conda, mamba

I'm building a snakemake workflow and one of the rules uses the `sort` command line utility, and it uses the `-k` option, but I cannot find a corresponding conda package for that utility.  My workflow is using:

```
(ATACCD) $ which sort
/usr/bin/sort
(ATACCD) $ sort --version
2.3-Apple (154)
```

`conda search sort` (or rather `mamba search sort`) shows tons of packages, but none of them are clearly the regular plain old `sort` command line utility.

I'm using channels:

- bioconda
- conda-forge
- defaults
  Is it on another channel?  I'm still getting comfortable with conda/mamba, so I'm guessing there's some obvious thing I'm missing...

I've looked specifically at what seemed to me to be the most likely candidates (the short named ones: `gsort`, `usort`, `natsort`).  Is there like some general `*nix` environment I should be using?

My base environment doesn't have a `sort` in it, nor does the environment I'm currently using (`ATACCD`).  And miniconda is the first thing in my `PATH`:

```
(ATACCD) $ echo $PATH
/Users/rleach/.miniconda3/envs/ATACCD/bin:/Users/rleach/.miniconda3/condabin:/Library/...
```

### UPDATE: *And* I just found out that the `cat` package I included is wrong too:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - cat>=5.2.3
```

(It's actually in the bioconda channel, despite my yaml spec.)

My rule tries to use it and I get:

```
usage: CAT (prepare | contigs | bin | bins | add_names | summarise) [-v / --version] [-h / --help]
CAT: error: one of the arguments prepare contigs bin bins add_names summarise is required
```

The thing is that the snakemake linters require me to have a conda env file for every rule... How do I satisfy these basic requirements?

Comment: I regard it as best practice to always include `nodefaults` as a channel in YAML files. This isn't actually a channel, but instead a directive that tells the solver that it should not add any system- or user-level channels found in the configuration when creating the environment. (most of my YAMLs are for Snakemake pipelines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `conda-suggest` package](https://github.com/conda-incubator/conda-suggest) is useful for this. It is a database constructed from scraping all the `bin/` folders of all the Conda Forge packages. Unfortunately, it has been a few years since the database has been rebuilt, but it should cover most things.

```bash
# mamba install -n base conda-suggest
conda suggest message sort
Command 'sort' not found in the environment, but can be installed with any of:

    $ conda install -c conda-forge coreutils
```

That is, the `coreutils` package is what you are looking for. That is also what provides `cat`.